# Android ADK software that works in 2.3.4 and 3.1+ versions

Tags: android, arduino, adk

I made an [ADK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html) app that works in Android 2.3.4, but I need to make it work with tablets as well. Since the API changes, how can I manage this?

For example in 2.3.4 the method is `getAccessory` and in 3.1 is `openAccessory`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the method calls are not different. Only the package names are. 3.1 also supports the APIs contained in the com.android.future.usb package, so if you compile against the Google Add-on APIs in 3.1 as well, the same application should work. Let me know if you need more guidance.